# Move data to another table in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

How can you move all data in one table to another ?

```
tbl_1: id=1 name=Doe
tbl_2: (no data)
```

transfer data like this.

```
tbl_1: (no data)
tbl_2: id=1 name=Doe
```

Comment: If both tables are equal just run `INSERT INTO tbl_2 SELECT * FROM tbl_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a migration like below and then run :

```
PHP artisan migrate --path=pathToYourProject/database/migrations/transfer_from1_to2.php
```

transfer_from1_to2.php

```
$t1_data=Table1::all();
foreach ($t1_data as $d) {
    $t2 = new Table2;
    $t2->id = $d->id;
    $t2->name = $d->name;
    $t2->save();
    $d->delete();
}
```

Comment: that's what I'm gonna do with my controller, how am I gonna auto transfer the data, am I gonna use cron job ?

Comment: Yah. Okay, thank you so much man, I'll look forward to learn this. thankss :)